# Populating checkboxes with data from database

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, if-statement

How do I populate each checkbox with users role? Stupid thing to get stuck on but anything would help.

`$userRoles` is printing out JSON with all users and its roles

```
$total_row = $data->count();
            $output = "";
            if ($total_row > 0) {
                foreach ($data as $row) {
                    $roleNames = '';
                    $userRoles = $row->roles;
                    $checked = '';
                    foreach (Role::all() as $roles1) {
                        if (in_array($roles1, (array)$userRoles)) {
                            $checked = 'checked="checked"';
                        }
                        $roleNames .= $roles1->role != null ? $roles1->role.' '.'<input type="checkbox" '.$checked.' name="role" value="'.$roles1->id.'" class="checkbox" id="checkboxId">'.' ' : '';
                    }
                    $output .= '
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$row->surname.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row->name.'</td>
                            <td>'.$row->phone.'</td>
                            <td>'.$roleNames.'</td>
                            <td>'.$userRoles.'</td>
                            <td><button type="button" id="rowId" class="remove-button btn btn-danger" data-id="'.$row->id.'">
                            <div class="close">&#120;</div>
                            </button></td>
                        </tr>
                    ';
                }
```

Comment: It seems correct, where exactly is your problem? You can't output the restult html string?

Comment: All your checkbox inputs have the same `name` (not even an array) and ID. how do you recover the data after showing the HTML ? and `<td>'.$userRoles.'</td>` will print a json structure no ?

Comment: it does not populate the checkbox, yes, $userRoles prints json

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by other people, you have errors in your `name` and `id` attributes for the checkboxes, as currently they will always be the same.  However there is a bigger more sinister problem here.

```
        $checked = '';
        foreach (Role::all() as $roles1) {
            if (in_array($roles1, (array)$userRoles)) {
                $checked = 'checked="checked"';
            }
            $roleNames .= $roles1->role != null ? $roles1->role . ' ' . '<input type="checkbox" ' . $checked . ' name="role" value="' . $roles1->id . '" class="checkbox" id="checkboxId">' . ' ' : '';
        }
```

This block of code loops over all the roles and updates the `$checked` variable with a string if the user has the role.  Problem is, the `$checked` variable is ***outside*** the loop. So if on the first iteration it passes the truth test, it updates the variable to the string 'checked="checked"', but if all the other roles do not pass, they do not change the variable back to empty, so all check boxes would be checked.

Without seeing what the json structure of the roles are, this is about as best as I can comment.